# Writing a GCD of two numbers as a linear combination

Tags: abstract-algebra, algorithms, divisibility

I am working on GCD's in my Algebraic Structures class.  I was told to find the GCD of 34 and 126.  I did so using the Euclidean Algorithm and determined that it was two.  I was then asked to write it as a linear combination of 34 and 126 and I am really unsure of how to do so.  I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Run the Euclidean algorithm "backwards".  You will have already
$$\eqalign{
  126&=3\times34+24\cr
  34&=1\times24+10\cr
  24&=2\times10+4\cr
  10&=2\times4+2\ .\cr}$$
Now rewrite all these to make the remainder the subject (with practice you will find you can omit this step but it's a good thing to do initially).  We get
$$\eqalign{
  2&=10-2\times4\cr
  4&=24-2\times10\cr
  10&=34-1\times24\cr
  24&=126-3\times34\ .\cr}$$
Finally substitute each remainder into the previous equation, collecting terms at each step:
$$\eqalign{
  2&=10-2\times(24-2\times10)\cr
  &=-2\times24+5\times10\cr
  &=-2\times24+5\times(34-1\times24)\cr
  &=5\times34-7\times24\cr
  &=5\times34-7\times(126-3\times34)\cr
  &=-7\times126+26\times34\ .\cr}$$
This shows $2$ as a constant times $126$ plus a constant times $34$.

Comment: I don't understand how in the third part you got from the first step to the second. Where did the five come from?

Comment: $5=1-2(-2)\,\!$.

Answer (score 6):

Use the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242) to compute the Bezout identity for the gcd.

$$\begin{array}{rrr}
126 &  1 &    0\\
34 &  0 &  1\\
 24 &  1 & -3\\
   10 & -1&   4\\
    4 & 3 & -11\\
  2 & \!\!\color{#c00}{-7} & \!\!\!\color{#0a0}{26}\end{array}\qquad$$

where each above line $\,\ a\ \ b\ \ c\ \,$ means that $\ a = 126\, b + 34\, c.\ $ Therefore

$$ 2 = -\color{#c00}{7}\cdot 126 + \color{#0a0}{26}\cdot 34\qquad$$

The linked post described the algorithm in great detail, in a way that is easy to remember.

Here is another example computing $\rm\ gcd(141,19),\,$ with the equations written *explicitly*

$\qquad\qquad\rm\begin{eqnarray}
[\![1]\!]\ \ \ \, \color{#C00}{141}\!\ &=&\,\ \  1&\cdot& 141\, +\ 0&\cdot& 19 \\
[\![2]\!]\quad\ \color{#C00}{19}\ &=&\,\ \  0&\cdot& 141\, +\ 1&\cdot& 19 \\
\color{#940}{[\![1]\!]-7\,[\![2]\!]}\, \rightarrow\, [\![3]\!]\quad\ \ \ \color{#C00}{ 8}\ &=&\,\ \  1&\cdot& 141\, \color{darkorange}{-\ 7}&\cdot& 19 \\
\color{#940}{[\![2]\!]-2\,[\![3]\!]}\,\rightarrow\,[\![4]\!]\quad\ \ \ \color{#C00}{3}\ &=& {-}2&\cdot& 141\, + \color{#90f}{15}&\cdot& 19 \\
\color{#940}{[\![3]\!]-3\,[\![4]\!]}\,\rightarrow\,[\![5]\!]\quad \color{#C00}{{-}1}\ &=&\,\ \  7&\cdot& 141\, -\color{#0A0}{ 52}&\cdot& \color{#0A0}{19}
\\ 
{\rm negating}\ \Rightarrow\ \ \ \ \ \ {1}\ &=&  {-}7&\cdot& 141\, +\color{#0A0}{ 52}&\cdot& \color{#0A0}{19}\ \ \ \rm [Bezout\ equation]
\end{eqnarray}$

The prior Bezout equation $\Rightarrow 141^{-1}\equiv \color{c00}{-7}\pmod{\!19},\,$ & $\,\color{#0a0}{19^{-1}\!\equiv 52}\pmod{\!141}\,$ by reducing the Bezout equation $\bmod19\,$ and $\bmod 141\,$ resp., as [explained here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3290965/242). Thus we see that using the extended Euclidean algorithm to compute the gcd Bezout equation  yields one method of computing modular inverses (and fractions). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2368266/242) & [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3434593/242) for  more examples of this and related methods.

Equivalently $\!\bmod 141\!:\ \dfrac{0}{\color{#c00}{141}}\overset{\large\frown}\equiv\dfrac{1}{\color{#c00}{19}}\overset{\large\frown}\equiv\dfrac{\color{darkorange}{-7}}{\color{#c00}8}\equiv\dfrac{\color{#90f}{15}}{\color{#c00}{3}}\equiv\dfrac{\color{#0a0}{-52}}{\color{#c00}{-1}}\Rightarrow \color{#0a0}{19^{-1}\equiv 52},\,$ where we used a succinct [fractional form](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2053174/242) of the above extended Euclidean algorithm, which boils down to viewing the above equations $\!\bmod 141.$

Comment: @user115241 A piece of advice. In my experience, students make *far* more mistakes using the back-substitution method in the other answer. Because of this I strongly recommend to my students the above method, which completely avoids the messy and error-prone back-substitution process.

Comment: @Geoff  Yes, that typo is now fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We can also say that; $a=b(q)+r$, from our equation $a=126,b=34$, $q$ being the quotient and $r$ the remainder. Hence

$$126=34(3)+24$$

Next $a=34$ and $b=24$, then

$$34=24(1)+10$$

Following the process we will find:

$$24=10(2)+4$$
$$10=4(2)+2$$
$$4=2(2)=0$$

Our GCD is the last remainder of the non-zero equation, 2. When writing as a linear combination we start from the non-zero equation. I.e.

$$10=4(2)+2$$

Making 2 the subject:

$$2=10-4(2)$$

But $24=10(2)+4$.
We can write 
$$4=24-10(2)$$

Substituting in $2=10-4(2)$ we find

$$2=10-(24-10(2))2$$
$$2=10-24(2)+10(4)$$
$$2=10(1)+10(4)-24(2)$$
$$2=10(5)-24(2)$$

This implies that $50-48=2$ which is our GCD.