# What is the value of $x,y$ where $A\cdot x+B\cdot y=\gcd(A,B)$?

Tags: algorithms, education

For example, I have two integer $A=9, B=15$.
Here the $\gcd(9,15) = 3$.

If I take two integer $x=2$ and $y=-1$ then
$9\cdot2 + 15\cdot(-1)$ will be equal to $3$ which is $\gcd(9,15)$.

So, what will be the **general formula** to find the value of $x$ and $y$ for any given $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Are you familiar with Euclid's algorithm?

Comment: Yes, I know how find gcd of two numbers using Euclid's algorithm.

Comment: Then can't you find the values of $x,y$ via the same procedure?

Comment: Sorry, i don't get it. I know this formula/algorithm (from this website [https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/euclid-algorithm.html]. But, I am unable to find value of x,y using same algorithm.

Comment: Check the answer posted and this link from math.stack that contains more than one methods-https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/665389/writing-a-gcd-of-two-numbers-as-a-linear-combination

Answer (score 0):

By applying Euclid'Algorithm [you can find](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/665389/writing-a-gcd-of-two-numbers-as-a-linear-combination) both the gcd for given $A,B \in \mathbb{Z}$ as well as a pair of $x,y$.

That said, $x,y$ are **not** unique in this expression.

Indeed, let $$gcd(A,B)=d=xA+yB$$
Then we have: $$d=xA+yB=\\(x-B)A+(y+A)B=\\xA-AB+yB+AB=\\xA+yB$$

So we can create an infinite number of $x^*,y^*$ such that $x^*A+y^*B=d$

Comment: Thank you so much. I get it now.

Comment: @Arafat_19AK My pleasure.