# How do I simplify a modular congruence?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If I have $$13x\equiv 15 \pmod{35}$$ or something like $$197x\equiv -1 \pmod{371}$$
How do I go about making the coefficient of the $13x$ and $197x$ $1$? Brute forcing this would take far too long. I know that you can use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm and Modular Inverses to solve, but I am unsure how.

Comment: May be try with its factor like $5.7=35$, then use the Chinese Remainder Theorem. Do you know its proof btw? If so, apply them should easily yield the answer. It obviously still take long, but works best for large numbers like $371$

Comment: For large moduli, the extended Euclidean (or its variants) is exactly the way to go.

Comment: " I know that you can use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm and Modular Inverses to solve, but I am unsure how." Then what are you asking?  It is not a reasonable question to ask us to teach you how to use modular inverses when you haven't learned them yet.  All we can say is *read* and *learn* about Modular inverses.  When you do and if you have a question ask us about it.

Comment: @fleablood I think you misunderstand that. As I see it Leo Sun is aware that he can use these methods to solve the exercise, but struggles to perform the method.

Comment: See the linked dupes for most all of the known methods (and see the "Linked" questions there for many more worked examples).

Answer (score 0):

You have that $\operatorname{gcd}(35,13)=1$. This enables us to find a linear combination

$35a+13b=1$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$. This is known as Bézout's Identity.

This is done as follows.

With the euclidean algorithm you can caculate the greatest common divisor, in this case $1$, like this:

$$35=2\cdot 13+9$$

$$13=1\cdot 9+4$$

$$9=2\cdot 4+1$$

$$4=1\cdot 4+0$$

Now to get the linear combination, we reverse this process, by substituting in the expression.

We want to get a linear combination in terms of $35$ and $13$ that equals $1$.

We start with the equality $9=2\cdot 4+1\Leftrightarrow 1=9-2\cdot 4$.

Now we solve the equation in the preceeding line (in the algorithm) for $4$ and substitute that in.

We have $4=13- 9$, hence

$1=9-2(13-9)=3\cdot 9-2\cdot 13$.

Now we do the same for $9$. This gives us:

$1=3(35-2\cdot 13)-2\cdot 13=3\cdot 35-8\cdot 13$, and we have found the linear combination.

So now we have

$3\cdot 35-8\cdot 13=1\Leftrightarrow 8\cdot 13=3\cdot 35-1$

Which is equivalent to $8\cdot 13\equiv -1\mod 35$.

Now multiply this by $-15$ (or $20\mod 35$).

This gives

$160\cdot 13\equiv 15\mod 35$.

So $x=160\equiv 20\mod 35$ solves the equation $13x\equiv 15\mod 35$.

The other equation can be solved similar, and is left as an exercise.
You will be able to solve this, when you go carefully line through line by the scetched method above.

Note that in the other example we also have that $\operatorname{gcd}(197,371)=1$.
That the gcd is here 1 makes it simpler to manipulate the equation (by multiplying at the end) to get the desired inverse. As we are not working in a field here (35 and 371 are not prime) you will not always find an inverse using this method, or at all.

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you don't know how to use modular inverses (which *is* the way to do this and you *should* learn it) you can do it just be setting up equations

$13x \equiv 15 \pmod {35}$ means there exists an integer $m$ so that $13x =15 + 35m$ so $x = \frac{15 + 35m}{13}= 1 + 2m +\frac {2+9m}{13}$.

This means that $13|2+9m$ so $2+9m\equiv 0\pmod {13}$ and so $9m\equiv -2 \equiv 11\pmod {13}$.

That means there is an integer $n$ so that $9m = 11 + 13n$ and $m=\frac {11+13n}9=(n+1) + \frac {2+4n}9$.

That means $4n \equiv -2\equiv 7\pmod 9$.  Let $4n = 7 +9p$ so $n = \frac {7+9p}4 =(2p+1) + \frac{3+p}4$.

That means $p\equiv -3 \equiv 1\pmod 4$.

Let $p = 4z + 1$.

So $n = (2p+1) + \frac{3+p}4 = (2(4z+1)+1) + \frac {4z + 4}4 = 8z+3 + z + 1 =9z + 4$.

So $m =(n+1) + \frac {2+4n}9 = (9z+5) + \frac {2+4(9z+4)}9=(9z+5)+\frac{18+4\cdot 9z}9=(9z+5) + 2+4z = 13z +7$

So $x = 1 + 2m +\frac {2+9m}{13}= 1+2(13z +7) + \frac {2+9(13z+7)}{13}=(26z+15)+\frac {65 + 9\times 13z}{13}=(26z+15)+(5+9z)=20+35z$.

So $x \equiv 20 \pmod {35}$.

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: I was attempting to answer to OPs question of how to do this when one *doesn't* know how to use Euclid's Algorithm or modular inverses.  Thus I don't believe it is an exact dupe. (Although it is very very similar)